# How to start nodejs server and next js app at the same time using concurrently at our backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Need help to start nodejs server and next js app at the same time using concurrently npm package at our backend. I have written the script in package.json file on backend side but it's not working.

I don't know exactly know even the concurrently is exist for next js or not. The below script is working fine for React-App but not working for Next JS App

package.json (backend)

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.5",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "slugify": "^1.4.5",
    "string-strip-html": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

package.json(frontend)

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^9.5.5",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.13.6",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: is your project versioned in a github repository ? it's probably an issue caused by paths

Comment: Not versioned in github repo

Comment: i think the best way to use concurrently is to have your client and your server in the same project

Comment: The problem is only in this line  "client": "npm start --prefix frontend".

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json  file of the backend, you need to replace

```
"client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
```

with

```
"client": "cd ./frontend && npm run dev"
```

I am assuming that your Nextjs app is in the frontend folder/directory. change the folder accordingly. Then you can run npm run dev command from the backend directory.

Now you will be able to start nodejs server and next js app at the same time using concurrently npm package